# Angular Material date picker input treat the date as US format

Tags: angular, angular-material

When populating the date in the input field (not via the datepicker itself) date is treated as US format.
For example, after typing in input field - 10/01/2019 it becomes 01/10/2019 and when opening the date picker the date is first of October 2019.

when selecting the date via the date picker there is no issue and selected date is displayed as dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Please include an [mcve] via https://stackblitz.com

Comment: use the datePipe on your component. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: datePipe does not solve it. the problem is that the input which come from the text input is considered as US

Answer (score 12):

***UPDATE***
There was a "bug" in format function -need a parenthesis in ('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)-

just create a DateAdapter

```
import {NativeDateAdapter,DateAdapter} from '@angular/material';

export class MyDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter{
  parse(value: string) {
    let it=value.split('/');
    if (it.length==3)
    return new Date(+it[2],+it[1]-1,+it[0],12)
  }

  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object) {
    return ('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2)+'/'+
           ('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'/'+date.getFullYear()
  }
}
```

Then use as provider

```
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-formats-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-formats-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-formats-example.css'],
    providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter}
  ],

})
export class DatepickerFormatsExample {
  date = new FormControl(new Date(Date.now()));
}
```

see in

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xnzqq-vuureb?file=app/my-date-adapter.ts)

Comment: In my case, I just had to remove the "format()" function, and it works like a charm, Thanks!! :)

Comment: Nicolas, if you remove the "format() function, not show the date in format dd/MM/yyyy. There was a "bug" in the code (just corrected)

Comment: Maybe I have some configuration that make it work without this function ;), But Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: For later versions of angular material, you will find the `NativeDateAdapter, DateAdapter` modules under `@angular/material/core`.

Answer (score 1):

A fix that worked for me was to import the module `MatMomentDateModule` in the module where I have declared the component using the Material Datepicker.

Or of course you can add it in the imports/exports of your shared module so it can be imported in any other module.

FYI : In Angular Material Docs, I found this in an example of a Datepicker with locale :

```
/** @title Datepicker with different locale */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-locale-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-locale-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-locale-example.css'],
  providers: [
    // The locale would typically be provided on the root module of your application. We do it at
    // the component level here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'ja-JP'},
    // `MomentDateAdapter` and `MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS` can be automatically provided by importing
    // `MatMomentDateModule` in your applications root module. We provide it at the component level
    // here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
  ],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatButtonModule],
})
export class DatepickerLocaleExample implements OnInit {
```

As you can see in the last comment, they recommend importing `MatMomentDateModule`  at root module level, but it did not work for me.

Last but not least, it worked with and without the proposed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54117664) by Eliseo.

**EDIT** : Found the root cause which is the `MatNativeDateModule` being imported in my shared module. This made the DateAdapter instance not being a singleton one.
Moving it to the root module with `MatMomentDateModule` fixed the issue.
Here's my root module :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
      useHash: false,
    }),
    KeycloakAngularModule,
    SharedModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: "fr-FR" },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "fr" },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the angular material datepicker you can overide the locale wich is US by default.
see this link : https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization

You need to set the **useValue** to fr-FR or other locale that uses the dd/MM/yyyy

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR'},
  ],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

Comment: when setting the local as en-FR the date in the input is not converted but when opening the datepicker the date is US (for example input=9/1/2019, datepicker display first of September 2019)