# how to prevent Angular Material DatePicker from switching month and day?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am using Angular Material for my UI. Everything seems to be OK until i entered the date manually (without calandar). When i enter the date and click out of the input, the month and day get switched automatically.

By the way, i tried`{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR' }` to set the locale to french,
i event tried to set the local during runtime using `this.dateAdapter.setLocale('fr');` but i still have the same problem.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54129342/5120854 which does not have an accepted answer yet

Comment: check the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113765/angular-material-date-picker-input-treat-the-date-as-us-format