# Is there a way to change a component provider "useValue" in the initialization of the component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'date-input',
    templateUrl: './date-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./date-input.component.scss'],
    providers: [
         {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
    ]
})
export class DateInputComponent implements OnInit
```

Is there a way to change the "useValue" of the provider ("MY_FORMAT" object) in the constructor of the component?

Comment: yes, this is object and I want to change one of his field.

Comment: Are you looking for a DateAdapter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113765/angular-material-date-picker-input-treat-the-date-as-us-format/54117664#54117664 ?

Comment: Yes, but I used " MAT_DATE_FORMATS" with  {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]}, as material suggested in their documentation.