# Angular Material datepicker format for specific input

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

How can I control the format of input for a datepicker individually, without changing format for the whole module?

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date" [format]="'DD/MM/YYYY'"> <-- is this possible?
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: you can change the DateAdapter for one component, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113765/angular-material-date-picker-input-treat-the-date-as-us-format/54117664#54117664. But I'm not prety sure how do if you has two datePicker in the same component

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to change locale of date-picker to en-GB by adding {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'} to provider section of you module. Like below

```
@NgModule({providers: [{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'}]})
```

[Official doc for this](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization)

Comment: I want to format multiple inputs within the same module differently. If I do what you suggest, then every datepicker input will have the same format. What I asked is whether it is possible to format datepicker inputs individually.